# Can I force-mount a raid filesystem beyond repair?

Tags: raid, mdadm, superblock

I had a 3-disk RAID5 setup. While migrating carelessly, a disk popped out of the array and then another followed closely.

I therefore cannot legitimately rebuild the array because there is no aligned pair of disks.

I already cloned with dd two disks of the array into a pair of spare (identical) disks so that I can mess it up and start again as many times as I want.

I know that if the data doesn't match I would most likely get corruption, but I would like to try just as a means of learning something.

If I force-assemble the two disks I can start the array but then I cannot mount it because:

```
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md1 --assemble /dev/sde2 /dev/sdd2 -f 
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 2 drives (out of 3).


sudo mount -v /dev/md1 /media/mfloris/raidNas/ 
mount: /media/mfloris/raidNas: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

**Is there a way I can fiddle with the metadata to make the system believe that the disks are aligned?**

I already tried *fsck -n /dev/md1* (it does nothing) and *dumpe2fs /dev/md1* (it says bad magic number in superblock)

I also tried:

```
$sudo file -skL /dev/md1 
/dev/md1: BTRFS Filesystem sectorsize 4096, nodesize 16384, leafsize 16384, UUID=f0b84f7d-7247-4781-959d-1da2eea20e66, 407236403200/5999719088128 bytes used, 1 devices\012- data

$ sudo grep btrfs /proc/filesystems
    btrfs

$ lsmod | grep btrfs
btrfs                1138688  0
zstd_compress         163840  1 btrfs
xor                    24576  2 async_xor,btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  4 async_pq,btrfs,raid456,async_raid6_recov

sudo mount -t btrfs -v /dev/md1 /media/mfloris/raidNas/
mount: /media/mfloris/raidNas: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

$sudo btrfs check /dev/md1
parent transid verify failed on 654950400 wanted 8458 found 8456
parent transid verify failed on 654950400 wanted 8458 found 8456
parent transid verify failed on 654950400 wanted 8458 found 8460
parent transid verify failed on 654950400 wanted 8458 found 8460
Ignoring transid failure
leaf parent key incorrect 654950400
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

and the dangerous

```
$ sudo btrfsck --init-extent-tree /dev/md1 
Checking filesystem on /dev/md1
UUID: f0b84f7d-7247-4781-959d-1da2eea20e66
Creating a new extent tree
ERROR: tree block bytenr 169114808628 is not aligned to sectorsize 4096
Error reading tree block
error pinning down used bytes
ERROR: attempt to start transaction over already running one
extent buffer leak: start 653361152 len 16384
```

How can I try to fix the superblock?

This is the state of the devices. Event counter is close, update time is roughly 8 hours apart but the data was most likely untouched during that period.

```
$sudo mdadm -E /dev/sd*2
/dev/sdd2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b57aca26:65609077:9fe7889a:6241c63a
           Name : NAS:1
  Creation Time : Fri Aug  3 08:13:23 2018
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 5859101344 (2793.84 GiB 2999.86 GB)
     Array Size : 5859100672 (5587.67 GiB 5999.72 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5859100672 (2793.84 GiB 2999.86 GB)
   Super Offset : 5859101600 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=912 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bb700941:772cb7b0:db32a940:e902d0bd

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Aug 28 07:47:49 2018
       Checksum : 153fd25e - correct
         Events : 78660

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sde2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b57aca26:65609077:9fe7889a:6241c63a
           Name : NAS:1
  Creation Time : Fri Aug  3 08:13:23 2018
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 5859101344 (2793.84 GiB 2999.86 GB)
     Array Size : 5859100672 (5587.67 GiB 5999.72 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5859100672 (2793.84 GiB 2999.86 GB)
   Super Offset : 5859101600 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=912 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c844b66b:fe21447d:e74c865a:751baa07

Internal Bitmap : -16 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Aug 28 00:04:18 2018
       Checksum : 703361e6 - correct
         Events : 78660

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski edited

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I had turned off the pc, hence the empty response. Ignore that, I turned it on again and performed mdadm stop, mdadm force assembly to get back to the original scenario

Comment: Please read `man btrfs-check`. I think `btrfs check /dev/md1` is the right thing to try now. You can use `--repair`, possibly with `-s`. However I would see first what sole `btrfs check /dev/md1` yields. I have never done this and if your manual says "do not use `--repair` unless you are advised to by an experienced user" then it's not about me. If I were you I would ignore this warning and use `--repair` eventually, because of these copies that allow to start over in case of trouble.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I will read the manual for btrfs-check. I edited the question with the commands you suggested. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Compare [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233724).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I even tried the infamous "btrfsck --init-extent-tree" but it failed. I am however alarmed by "ERROR: tree block bytenr 169114808628 is not aligned to sectorsize 4096" : could this be the source of failure?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I use Btrfs but I have never tried (needed) to recover from similar situation. I don't understand it theoretically well enough to help you further.

Comment: One thing I would try (*but this is a shot in the dark really*) is `--init-extent-tree` with different values of `-s`.